# Laravel Spatie Sitemap Package, getting Auth pages too

Tags: laravel, sitemap, laravel-sitemap

This is my code in Laravel :

```
 SitemapGenerator::create('https://'.request()->getHost())->writeToFile(request()->getHost().'.xml');
```

After generating the sitemap I am getting this type of URLs

```
<url>
        <loc>https://example.com/login?redirectTo=https://example.com/posts/wvj/test</loc>
        <lastmod>2021-01-20T19:39:59+06:00</lastmod>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>0.8</priority>
    </url>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `add` method.

```php
SitemapGenerator::create('https://example.com')
   ->getSitemap()
   ->add(Url::create('/extra-page')
        ->setLastModificationDate(Carbon::yesterday())
        ->setChangeFrequency(Url::CHANGE_FREQUENCY_YEARLY)
        ->setPriority(0.1))

    ->add(...)

    ->writeToFile($path);
```

Comment: I want to get the same URLs without this `https://example.com/login?redirectTo=`